# Vue v-model lazy modifier not working on array elements

Tags: vuejs2, vee-validate

I have an array of objects which I iterate over with v-for and create an input for one of the object's properties and use vee-validate on that input. I want to validate lazily so I use v-model.lazy to update only on change and this is where the issue occurs. The data binding doesn't seem to happen correctly. The below fiddle reproduces my issue. Any advice would be much appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/1r944gnc/

```
Vue.use(VeeValidate)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    users: [
      {
        email: null
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {

  }
})

<div id="app">
    <div v-for="user in users">
      <input type="text" name="foo" v-model.lazy="user.email" v-validate="'email'" />
      <span v-show="errors.has('foo')">{{ errors.first('foo') }}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bug of VeeValidate.

There is a workaround which has same effect as your desire: Validate on `blur` event

```
<div id="app">
    <div v-for="user in users">
      <div>Email: {{ user.email }}</div>
      <input type="text" name="foo" v-model="user.email" v-validate="'email'" data-vv-validate-on="blur"/>
      <span v-show="errors.has('foo')">{{ errors.first('foo') }}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/4zjf2ph3/